# How to configure and run a code inspection tool like FindBugs as a teamcity task?

Tags: teamcity, findbugs

Recently we moved to Contentious Integration for build management using Teamcity and also configured a few automated junit tests as ant tasks. To extend it further I'm looking at running a static code analysis tool like FindBugs as a step whenever a build triggers. I would appreciate any helpful suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run FindBugs  or other command line tool from TeamCity easy.  Just create a command line task, point to your exe and off you go.  Sonar is also another very good tool, here is a sample instance http://nemo.sonarqube.org/